# pinlabel doesn't work after upgrade to luatex 0.95

Tags: luatex, bounding-box

I use extensively `pinlabel` package in my project, which I compile with LuaLaTeX. After recent MiKTeX 2.9 upgrade, I cannot compile the project any more, getting numerous errors like

```
! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \pdfximagebbox 
               \pdflastximage 1 
l.19    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pdf_figure}
```

and

```
! Undefined control sequence. 
 <argument> \pdfximagebbox 
               \pdflastximage 2 l.19    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pdf_figure}
```

After analysing the log files and reading similar error reports here on TSE, I think the problem might be caused by LuaTeX 0.95 and the following lines in `pinlabel`, determining the bounding box of a pdf image:

```
%  Next five lines of code supplied by Mark Petelier
%  
%  Read BB from pdf file:
%
         \pdfximage cropbox {\@filestem.pdf}
         \@p@@sbbllx{\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 1}
         \@p@@sbblly{\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 2}
         \@p@@sbburx{\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 3}
         \@p@@sbbury{\pdfximagebbox\pdflastximage 4}
```

The LuaTeX manual suggests I should use external applications or img library to replace `\pdfximagebbox` command, however, my knowledge of (Lua)TeX is not enough to implement it. Thus my question is: what's the best way to get `pinlabel` work with LuaTeX 0.95?

MWE:

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///lualatex/
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
% the following package seems to be necessary to enable use of pdf images with pinlabel after upgrade to luatex 0.95 
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{pinlabel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
    Math in graphics: \\
    \labellist    
    \pinlabel $X$ at 200 200
    \endlabellist
%   Two cases, uncomment one of them
%
%   MWE compiles well with the following line; the BB information is taken from the corresponding example-image.eps file, I guess
%   \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
%
%   MWE does not compile with lualatex 0.95 if using any pdf file without corresponding eps file. The examle compiles well usin pdftex.
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pdf_figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the LuaTeX manual: “The introspective primitives `\pdflastximagecolordepth` and `\pdfximagebbox` have been removed. One can use external applications to determine these properties or use the built-in `img` library.” As usual, there is no example whatsoever. `:(`

Comment: @egreg I think it's a question of doing `a = img.new({filename='foo.pdf'})` then `a.bbox` and `a.colordepth`

Comment: @JosephWright or here I think you can just scan for height and depth, see below

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you can patch the code to use the lua image library like so:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,twoside,a4paper]{article}
% the following package seems to be necessary to enable use of pdf images with pinlabel after upgrade to luatex 0.95 
\usepackage{luatex85}
\usepackage{pinlabel}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1\pdfximage#2\no@bbfalse#3\foo{%
\def\scan@header{#1%
         \directlua{a = img.scan { filename = "\@filestem.pdf"}
tex.print(\the\catcodetable@atletter,
"\string\\@p@@sbburx{" .. a.width .. "sp}\string\\@p@@sbbury{" .. a.height .. "sp}")
}%
         \@p@@sbbllx{\z@}%
         \@p@@sbblly{\z@}%
        %
\no@bbfalse#3}}%
\expandafter\foo\scan@header\foo
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Math in graphics: \\
    \labellist    
    \pinlabel $X$ at 200 200
    \endlabellist
%   Two cases, uncomment one of them
%
%   MWE compiles well with the following line; the BB information is taken from the corresponding example-image.eps file, I guess
%   \includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image}
%
%   MWE does not compile with lualatex 0.95 if using any pdf file without corresponding eps file. The examle compiles well usin pdftex.
    \includegraphics[width=5cm]{pdf_figure}
\end{document}
```

perhaps could use bbox instead of height +depth, but for pdf file inclusion I think llx and lly will always be 0 anyway.

Comment: Thanks a  lot, this works perfectly! I have a question -- why the patch here is not ended by `\makeatother` as usual? Moreover, MWE doesn't compile if I add this command.

Comment: @OlegSoloviev try now: I forced the tex.print to use the correct catcodes even when `@` is set back to normal.

Comment: Thanks again; I've just checked it not only with MWE, but with my 200 pages project; with addition of `pgfsys-luatex.def` I can now work even after updating to LuaTeX 0.95 :-)