# Does pinlabel work with xelatex/lualatex?

Tags: xetex, luatex, labels

Does {pinlabel} work with xelatex or lualatex?

The following MWE works fine in pdflatex, but in xelatex/lualatex the figure disappears -- with no errors.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pinlabel}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\labellist
% \hair 2pt
% \pinlabel$\Out$ at 265 656
\endlabellist
\includegraphics[scale=4]{cat}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

where `cat.eps` is `texmf-dist/doc/latex/graphics/cat.eps`.

I am aware of the [answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312166/pinlabel-doesnt-work-after-upgrade-to-luatex-0-95/312342#312342) but it did not work for me on TL 2018.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `pinlabel` redefines `\includegraphics` to use `\psfig`, which is an obsolete command and is not understood by more recent engines.

Comment: @egreg What would be a recommended labeling package to use with xelatex/lualatex?

Comment: Maybe `overpic`.

Comment: @egreg The `pinlabel` manual has a _critique_ of other packages and it comes pretty hard on `overpic`  ... "overpic is the most basic. Reading label positioning is pure guesswork (using a simple grid) and there are no fine adjustments for positioning, which makes the final tuning very time-consuming (and highly sensitive to any last-minute change of scale)."

Comment: @PauloNey As I said, `pinlabel` is ***much*** worse as it redefines standard commands in terms of obsolete ones. Maybe the idea is better, but using `\psfig` is really a stopper.